# Having trouble compiling a Java program, I am new to it. Can't figure out what to do with directories

Tags: java, compilation

I have been searching the web trying to find the answer to my question, but everywhere I look seems to have too complex of a solution for a beginner like me. I have been working on this project, and just now realized that I should've made a package, or something like that. The thing is though, my program was working fine until I started dabbling with it, and now it won't work at all. I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: BubbleSort. class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BubbleSort.class
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:672)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
        at ``java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:638)
Could not find the main class: BubbleSort.class.  Program will exit.
```

Here's how my "path" looks, if I am not mistaken. I am connected to my school's Z: drive through a remote connection, and from there I have a folder called myFirstname_Lastname_A4,
which then leads me to another folder called sortingzz which I believe is supposed to have only my source files, but it also ended up with my class files in there whenever I compiled. So here's what I am doing to compile.

```
 cd myFirstname_Lastname_A4/sortingzz
```

`javac *.java` (Works fine, this is where I end up with my Class files inside of my sortingzz folder)

`java *` (This is where I get the error)

I am pretty sure I am just trying to run the program wrong. Before I started messing around with stuff I wasn't ready for, I used to just run the file with my main function in it, like this

```
javac SortingImplementation.java

java SortingImplementation
```

And that for the most part worked fine, but I started having trouble calling certain classes from other classes, so thats when I found out I was suppose to do the packaging and importing stuff.

In case that is the issue, I have on the top line of every source file:
package sortingzz;

and I am importing like this:

`import sortingzz.*`;

This is correct, right?

UPDATE:

I decided to give up on class pathing and trying to package everything, because as usual, I am getting responses that are way over my head, and to be honest I don't think it is necessary.

After removing package and importing from everything, and once again compiling using javac *., it actually compiles this time. However whenever I try to run my class with the main in it, SortingImplementation, it tells me that

```
Could not find the main class: SortingImplementation.  Program will exit.
```

I don't get it, I am looking at the SortingImplementation.class right now, with all the other classes and java files, so I am not sure what it's trying to do.

Comment: You need to point to the directory where the package is using `-cp` flag

Answer (score 1):

`javac *.java` is fine. This will compile your files. However, you only need to run the file with your main method in it: `java MainClass`

Comment: OP is probably not declaring his class `public`.

Comment: I am, I just decided to hell with class pathing and packaging, so I took it all off and it compiled fine. But now whenever I try to do java SortingImplementation, my class with the main function, it basically gives me the same error. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SortingImplementation

Comment: @user2993636 After you recompiled everything with javac *.java you still get the ClassDef error? Are you sure that all of your java source files are in your current directory? Try java -cp . SortingImplementation

Answer (score 1):

You say that you are using packages to organize the classes. In this case you need to set the class path using the `-cp` flag.

`javac -cp /path/to/parent/of/package classname.java`
and
`java classname`

Also, your main class should be declared `public` and should have a `main()`

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError occures when a class was recognised in compile time but was not available during runtime.
So the JVM can't find your class in the classpath.

using -cp flag to specify where your package is should work.

Answer (score 0):

the commanc `javac *.java` compiles all found java files to corresponding `.class` files. If you all your classfiles are in the same folder, which they should, you just run your regular `java SortingImplementation` command.

`java *` would, a bit depending on your OS, yield in an undesired command. For instance, on Linux it would be expanded by the OS to `java SortingImplementation.java SortingImplementation.class BubbleSort`. The last one is a directory, which ofcourse is not an executable class.

Comment: Ok, So I have all of my .java files in a folder, and it seems to me that everyone is telling me my .class files need to be in a seperate folder. So, is the folder with the classes supposed to be inside my .java files folder, or is it supposed to be somewhere else? I only ask because whenever I compile, the .class files are automatically created inside the folder with my .java files.

Comment: When you are starting to learn the language, it is not a problem at all to have your .java and .class files in the same folder. But we are indeed used to seperate them, so we have a good workspace seperation. Also, if you are getting to packages, you will note that the .class files will end up in a directory structure similar to the packagename. If you use an IDE like Eclipse, or a build tool like maven, then it will be done for you.